# MySQL where condition with only a reference to a column, what does it mean?

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, where-clause

Examples:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.col1

SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.col1 AND t.col2
```

Depending the nature of the column these queries behaves differently. In my tests, if the column is of the type integer wont show rows with 0s or nulls for that column, if it string, the query will give no result.

I'd like to understand what these types of where conditions mean. Couldn't find any specification for this in the MySQL manual nor an explanation online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your query you  are not assigning a valid comparision in the where clause (eg: `where t.col1 = 10`) ..  so the where condtion try to eval  a casting for the value in the columns mentioned as boolen

in this case  the diffent result is just based on the different casting in boolean of each type

if you firts query based  on a integer return always a valid true result so yoi get all the rows in the others with string depending of each string value this can produce no rows ,, partial rows or all rows .. try look at the result for the cast of your column in boolean

```
    SELECT if(t.col1, true, false)
    FROM table t
    WHERE t.col1
```

and

```
    SELECT if( t.col1 AND t.col2, true,false)
    FROM table t
    WHERE t.col1 AND t.col2
```

Answer (score 1):

Those just aren't proper boolean expressions. Boolean expressions evaluate to either true or false and are of the form `where t.col1 = 0 and t.col2 >= 3` for example.

The fact that your statements sometimes return data and sometimes not is due to the fact, that 0 and 1 stands for false and true respectively.

Like you already observed, 0 and NULLs don't return rows because they are treated as false in case of 0 and not comparable in case of NULL. Strings on the other hand are implicitly converted to numbers. If the string starts with a number other than 0, the string is converted to that number in MySQL. If the string starts with anything other than that, it's converted to 0. That's why you don't get results for strings.

I would recommend to **not** use these "short hand boolean expressions". Always write proper expressions!